# doctrine2 arrayresult foreign key

Tags: doctrine-orm, foreign-keys

Is there Way to get Foreign key in ArrayResult ? I have entity with ManyToOne reference to self. I want cache results, but If try cache ResultObject, i get error about serializing and __sleep. So, i try cache arrayResult, but foreign key don't show in array.

Thank for any help.